# Best practice to create a Summary Table for an ever-growing table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a table called `transactions` with ~20 million records. This table grows every second.

I calculate users current balance with:

```
SELECT sum(`amount`) FROM `transactions` WHERE `user_id` = 1000;
```

I'm showing user current balance in top bar of my web application and user can see how much balance he/she has!

Obviously every time a user browses my web app pages, the above query must be executed to calculate the current user balance!

I want to create a Summary Table to obtain the current user balance without querying on that `transactions` table with ~20 million records!

Be aware that in our workflow it's so common that a user may have multiple transactions simultaneously (a user may even have multiple transactions in just one second).

I think we have two approaches here:

**The First Approach**

Creating a Summary Table with One-To-One relationship as below:

```
ID  |  user_id  |  current_balance
1   |  1000     |      8590
2   |  1001     |      235
3   |  1002     |      3780
... |  ...      |      ...
```

And every time a new record inserted into the `transactions` table we trigger a stored procedure to update the user `current_balance` in the Summary Table.

I don't know if this approach breaks MySQL consistency or not!

**The Second Approach**

Creating a Summary Table with One-To-Many relationship as below:

```
ID  |  user_id  |  amount
1   |  1000     |   8590    <--- it's the initial user balance
2   |  1001     |   235     <--- it's the initial user balance
3   |  1002     |   3780    <--- it's the initial user balance
4   |  1000     |   50
5   |  1000     |   -30
6   |  1001     |   10
7   |  1002     |   60
8   |  1000     |   -45
```

We clear out our Summary Table nightly (for example at `00:00 AM`) and recalculate the current balance for all users from `transactions` table and insert them into the Summary Table. To determine a user's current balance we just need to do this:

```
SELECT sum(`amount`) FROM `users_balance` WHERE `user_id` = 1000;
```

But there is something that worries me about this approach. What if some users do transactions exactly at the time we are recalculating the users current balance and putting them into the Summary Table! ( exactly at `00:00 AM`)

Does this approach break consistency?

---

Please tell me if you know any better practice for this workflow.

**P.S.**

Our web app is an SMS panel via which users can send/receive/etc. SMS through the panel directly or an API. We have some users who send 1 million or more SMS in a day!

Every time an SMS is sent, a new record must be inserted in the `transactions` table.

I know 20 million records is not a big deal and we can achieve good performance with indexes, but as I mentioned above it's an ever-growing table. I'm pretty sure next year we'll have hundreds of millions records in `transactions` table.

Comment: 1. What is the consequence of presenting a slightly inaccurate -- slightly out-of-date -- balance to the user in your top bar? Does your application permit that?    2. Have you created a compound index on `(userid, amount)` and measured the performance of your `SUM()` query? Twenty megarows isn't really a lot if you're indexed correctly. You may not actually need your summary table,

Comment: I think this calls for professional help.

Comment: @O.Jones See updates

Comment: @O.Jones If we presenting a slightly inaccurate balance, users can send SMS while they don't have enough balance! Because before a user send SMS, we check user balance.

Comment: If `User has Balance` then it belongs in the User row. Calulating it from a transaction table makes no sense at all.

Comment: Did you ask a similar question?  Where I suggested you work like a bank and keep a nightly balance?  And then simply add to it the day's transactions?

Comment: @RickJames. Yes dear Rick. I'm trying to implement your suggestion. I confused a bit!

Comment: @HamedKamrava - Never mind; go with OJoine's `transactions` & `balances` tables; it is probably better.

Answer (score 4):

You're maintaining a balance for each user, as you have explained.

Your best bet is to write application code that carries out two queries, perhaps in a transaction, but probably not.

One query:

```
      UPDATE balances
         SET current_balance = current_balance - 1 
       WHERE user_id = 1000
```

That query, in itself, maintains consistency without any need for a transaction.

(**Edit**) It looks for the row of the `balances` table with `user_id=1000` and then subtracts one from the value of `current_balance` in that row, reading, modifying, then writing the row.  You can do this kind of arithmetic with column values in `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries as needed.

The other query

```
      INSERT INTO transactions (columns) VALUES (values)
```

The way you have explained your application, it sounds like the integrity of your business depends upon the table I'm calling `balances` in my first query. The `transactions` table is a log of user activity, and serves to explain how a customer balance got to be what it is.  So, if you get your application to perform the two queries I propose in order, you will have excellent balances values and good-enough logging. That's a good way to structure a transactional database.

Why should your `balances` be maintained separately from your transaction log? What if you want to give a customer 100 free messages? What if you want to start charging extra for messages at a certain time of day?  What if a customer demands a credit for a batch of messages that were, according to her, handled incorrectly?  If you make your balances from your transactions table, you're going to have to put all sorts of bizarre stuff into that table to handle your evolving business rules.

Would I bury the update of the `balances` table in a trigger if I were you? No, I would not. I'd make it part of your application. Easier to see, easier to debug, etc.

Comment: If a user sends a batch of messages we just insert one record in `transactions` table, of course we set a flag to see which one is batch and which one not.

Comment: I don't get well your first query `"current_balance = current_balance - 1 "` what you mean by `current_balance - 1` ?

Comment: See my edit. It subtracts one from the `current_balance` value in the table.  With respect, if you're programming an application with gigarow tables, you better hit the books on SQL. http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a favorite of mine.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your *First Approach* looks cool but I think you just need to calculate the new value depending on the transaction (example if it's credit/debit).

But why you are hitting database each and every time instead you can use a session variable to maintain the same and use synchronization while making any transaction with the amount and update the same in your summary table.

You should also use database indexes, bind variables [in the application] to increase the performance.

**(If you don't want to do all these things, a very simple solution is partitioning. You can create the datewise partition on transaction table with indexes and bind variable [in the application], which will do the same thing you want to achieve with above two methods.)**

Your *Second Approach* has many issues like database overhead of recalculation which may down/slow your application and again somehow you are doing the calculation.

Comment: Thank you. But what do you mean by saying `bind variable`? Do you mean I create a session variable in the app?

Comment: The bind variable is a database feature which helps you to skip query compilation at the database level and increase application performance. more details : http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html

Comment: Why don't you go for partitioning?

Comment: Yes partitioning can be another solution. I'm trying to find out how many approaches I could have!

Comment: You also can use an in-memory database to increase the performance.